# 301 redirects with variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

After searching the net I have found some code to write redirects with urls that have variables.

I am trying to redirect FROM: barkleyphoto.com/wedding/wedding-blog/?page_id=2
To: barkleyphoto.com/category/wedding-photography/

The code I have now:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=2
RewriteRule ^wedding/wedding-blog/.php$ /category/wedding-photography/? [L,R=301]

This code almost works but it takes me to barkleyphoto.com/?page_id=2 instead of where I want: barkleyphoto.com/category/wedding-photography/ WITH NO Variable.

Can someone help me modify this code to redirect to the proper place?

Comment: Are you using any form of CMS? These days most web applications simply redirect everything to an entry script (ie. index.php) and have a router to figure out what file to include/action to call based on the URL. This works better across different HTTP servers, avoids having to mess around with .htaccess and allows routes to be changed dynamically without editing the .htaccess file.

Comment: *that should be "rewrite everything" not "redirect everything".

Comment: I am using wordpress. But would those be 301 redirects? I have read that they better for SEO.